# javascript - Simulate keyboard input in browser (noticable by React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a js macro which will fill 3 inputs needed for login. I need to make this a lot of times in a day, so this would help a lot.

The problem is that something so simple like:

```
input_name.value = 'somevalue'
```

won't work, because the page I'm login into is using React.

I think I need to simulate pressing a keyboard key somehow.

Is it possible? I tried a lot of methods, but none worked.

I also tried few Chrome plugins for this (like iMacros), but all of them doesnt 'trigger' React's mechanism.

Anyone have some solution?

Answer (score 0):

iMacros should be able to simulate keypress using firefox/chrome plugins. [iMacros EVENT Documentation](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVENT)

If that doesn't work you could use a hardware solution such as a Teensy which can act as a keyboard/mouse